# Flutter:How can i change the color of selected menu item from drawer

Tags: flutter

I am creating an app in flutter, I have got some issue in drawer. I want to change the color of the selected drawer item.Here is my full code it looks fine to me but its not working for me... please help me find out what i am doing wrong

```
class _DrawerClassState extends State<DrawerClass> {
```

Here is my full code it looks fine to me but its not working for me... please help me find out what i am doing wrong

```
  List<String> menuStrings = [
    'HOME',
    'NOTIFICATIONS',
    'PARTNERS',
    'LOCATIONS',
    'FEEDBACK',
    'CONTACT US',
    'AWARDS'
  ];
Here is my full code it looks fine to me but its not working for me... please help me find out what i am doing wrong 

  List menuScreens = [
    HomeScreen(),
    Notifications(),
    Partners(),
    Locations(),
    FeedbackScreen(),
    const ContactUs(),
    Awards()
  ];
Here is my full code it looks fine to me but its not working for me... please help me find out what i am doing wrong 

  List<bool> isHighlighted = [false, false, false, false, true, false, false];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        canvasColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      child: Drawer(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            drawerTop("HI USER"),
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: menuScreens.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    for (int i = 0; i < isHighlighted.length; i++) {
                      setState(() {
                        if (index == i) {
                          isHighlighted[index] = true;
                        } else {
                          //the condition to change the highlighted item
                          isHighlighted[i] = false;
                        }
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  child: drawerItems(
                    context,
                    menuStrings[index],
                    menuScreens[index],
                    isHighlighted[index] ? Colors.amber : Colors.white,
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the method `drawerItems()` to build drawer items

```
  drawerItems(BuildContext context, String title, path, Color color) {
      return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 0.0, left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1),
          child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.of(context)
                    .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) => path)));
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                child: Text(
                  title,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: color,
                      fontFamily: "Raleway Reg",
                      fontSize: 23,
                      letterSpacing: 2),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
              child: const Divider(
                thickness: 1,
                color: Colors.white,
                height: 3,
              ),
            ),
          ]));
    }
```

Comment: what's inside your method `drawerItems` ?

Comment: @AbdallahA.Odeh i edited my question and added drawerItems method to it... please see

Comment: Hi I have the same case like you and tried to do @Abdallah A. Odeh solution, but I found out when I close the drawer..the color went back to the original, so the color only changed when drawer was open. did you also face it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `drawerItems`

```
drawerItems(BuildContext context, String title, path, Color color) {
  return Container(
      color: color,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 0.0, left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1),
      child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context)
                .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) => path)));
          },
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
            child: Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: color,
                  fontFamily: "Raleway Reg",
                  fontSize: 23,
                  letterSpacing: 2),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
          child: const Divider(
            thickness: 1,
            color: Colors.white,
            height: 3,
          ),
        ),
      ]));
}
```

the root widget that is returned from the method, change it from `Padding` to `Container` and give it a color

Comment: Thanks,this is working is this way but i need to change the color of text only... not whole container...

Comment: You are already using a dynamic color for the text, but I believe that white will not be visible, try using other colors such as `Colors.red` & `Colors.amber` to see if it changes when clicking it

Comment: drawer bg color was black that's why i was using white for text....

Comment: Hi, I have the same case like @UsmanHafeez and tried your solution, at first the color changed, but when I close the drawer, the color was back to the original. is there a way to avoid that ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a very complex solution to solve this simple task in Flutter.

I suggest my solution:
Publish it on my git:
https://github.com/igdmitrov/flutter-drawer

1. Create a new Abstract Page State:

> ```
> abstract class MyPageState<T extends StatefulWidget> extends State {
>   List<Widget> drawerItems(BuildContext context) {
>     return menuItems
>         .map(
>           (item) => ListTile(
>             leading: const Icon(Icons.my_library_books),
>             title: Text(
>               item['menuName'] as String,
>               style: TextStyle(
>                   color: isHighlighted[menuItems.toList().indexOf(item)]
>                       ? Colors.amber
>                       : Colors.grey),
>             ),
>             onTap: () {
>               isHighlighted = isHighlighted.map((mark) => false).toList();
>               isHighlighted[menuItems.toList().indexOf(item)] = true;
>               Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
>                   builder: ((context) => item['route'] as Widget)));
>             },
>           ),
>         )
>         .toList();
>   }
> }
> ```

Create drawer.dart file with code:

```
final menuItems = {
  {'menuName': 'HOME', 'route': const HomeScreen()},
  {'menuName': 'NOTIFICATIONS', 'route': const Notifications()},
};

List<bool> isHighlighted = [false, false];
```

And create pages:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  MyPageState<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends MyPageState<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Main page'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            const Text("HI USER"),
            ...drawerItems(context),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const [
            Text(
              'New app',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And Notifications page:

```
class Notifications extends StatefulWidget {
  static String routeName = '/notifications';
  const Notifications({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyPageState<Notifications> createState() => _NotificationsState();
}

class _NotificationsState extends MyPageState<Notifications> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Notifications'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            const Text("HI USER"),
            ...drawerItems(context),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const [
            Text(
              'Notifications page',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I have another question...when i navigate to any screen via drawer menu... when i reopen drawer it forgets which tile was selected

Comment: In my example on GitHub I don't have this issue, because we keep our variable in the different file.